# Stored Proc scope with Create table/view/index & Select in single SP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sql script creating views/tables/indexes and some selects all in the one script with GO statement after each table/view creation and i get errors.. It is possible hash them all in one script???

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ABC', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE dbo.ABC; 
GO

select v.*
INTO dbo.ABC
from dbo.BC v

GO

CREATE  NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ABC_ID  ON dbo.ABC ([ID])

GO

GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vABC] AS
SELECT [ID]
      ,[Description]
      ,[Name]
  FROM [dbo].[NewDRGTable]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXEC statement for each part like this (don't forget to escape apostrophe):

```
EXEC('IF OBJECT_ID(''dbo.ABC'', ''U'') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.ABC;')
```

etc.